# Rails postgresql left join using has_may order by created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-order-by, has-many

I have two models named as 'customer' and 'membership'. customer can have many memberships. I want to display customers in order of their latest memberships cancelled date in ascending or descending order. My query looks like this

```
@customers = Customer
  .joins('LEFT JOIN memberships on memberships.customer_id = customers.id')
  .includes(:partner, :affiliate, active_membership: :plan)
  .group('customers.id')
  .order('memberships.created_at DESC, memberships.cancelled_at DESC')
  .page(params[:page])
  .per(100)
```

Comment: Rails Version? Also you can do as follows `.select(Customer.arel_table[Arel.star],Membership.arel_table[:created_at].maximum.as('most_recent_membership')).group(:id).order(Membership.arel_table[:created_at].maximum.public_send(direction))` where direction is :asc or :desc. I left out the rest of your query for brevity. You would still need to left join memberships, add pagination, and your includes if you'd like, this will just allow you to sort by `MAX(memberships.created_at)` and have a virtual attribute called `Customer#most_recent_membership`

Comment: Rails 6 @engineersmnky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Customer
  has_many :memberships

  def self.order_by_latest_membership
     left_joins(:memberships) # no need to use a SQL string
       .group(:id) # you only need to group by customers.id
       .order(Membership.arel_table[:created_at].maximum.desc) # MAX(memberships.created_at) DESC
  end
end
```

```
Customer.order_by_latest_membership
        .includes(:partner, :affiliate, active_membership: :plan)
        .page(params[:page])
```

Comment: As hinted by @engineersmnky you can use also use `.select` if you want to get `MAX(memberships.created_at)` in the result set.

Comment: `left_joins` so that Users without memberships don't get left off the list